# Why is fluent-ffmpeg not concatenating my files?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I am trying to bundle up some mp3 and some jpg files into an mp4 file. When I run the code, an mp4 file is created but it is either empty or contains just the sound from the first mp3 file.

I've rejigged and rejigged the code but it's just not happening. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

````
const path = require("path");
  const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");

  let newMp4 = ffmpeg();
  newMp4
    .input(`${dirPath}/darkpatio.jpg`)
    .input(`${dirPath}/backgarden.jpg`)
    .input(`${dirPath}/sound_000000_NARRATOR.mp3`)
    .input(`${dirPath}/sound_000001_NARRATOR.mp3`)
    .input(`${dirPath}/sound_000002_NARRATOR.mp3`)
    .save(`${dirPath}/temp.mp4`)
    .outputFPS(12)
    .frames(2)
    .on("end", () => {
      console.log("done");
    ```
````